# Refactor Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Is there any way I can refactor this expression tree?

```
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T_PO> SortedPO(this IQueryable<T_PO> query,  ExtjsGridPagingParameter.SortingParameter sortingParameter)
    {

        IOrderedQueryable<T_PO> result = null;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortingParameter.property) == false)
        {                
            Expression<Func<T_PO, string>> orderField = null;
            Expression<Func<T_PO, DateTime?>> orderFieldDate = null;
            Expression<Func<T_PO, decimal>> orderFieldDecimal = null;
            switch (sortingParameter.property)
            {
                case "po_code":

                    orderField = (item => item.po_code);
                    break;

                case "proj_name":

                    orderField = (item => item.T_PROJECT.proj_name);
                    break;

                case "po_supplier_contact":

                    orderField = (item => item.po_supplier_contact);
                    break;

                case "po_grandtotal":

                    orderFieldDecimal = (item => item.po_grandtotal);
                    break;

                case "po_docdate":

                    orderFieldDate = (item => item.po_docdate);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }


            if (orderField != null)
            {
                if (sortingParameter.direction == "ASC")
                {
                    result = query.OrderBy(orderField);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = query.OrderByDescending(orderField);
                }
            }
            else if (orderFieldDate != null)
            {
                if (sortingParameter.direction == "ASC")
                {
                    result = query.OrderBy(orderFieldDate);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = query.OrderByDescending(orderFieldDate);
                }
            }
            else if (orderFieldDecimal != null)
            {
                if (sortingParameter.direction == "ASC")
                {
                    result = query.OrderBy(orderFieldDecimal);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = query.OrderByDescending(orderFieldDecimal);
                }
            }


        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Comment: Okay. It's got something to do with expression trees. Got it, *but what is this code supposed to do?* You've not given us enough context to properly review this code. What is its purpose? What are the expected inputs & outputs? Do you have any particular concerns about the code? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that your code will return `null` in case if the sort order is not defined. I've preserved this logic, but you may want to change it to return original query (and thus change return type to `IQueryable<T_PO>`).

You are doing 2 separate actions in this method, so if you split it into 2 parts you can get more compact and readable code:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool isAscending)
{
    return isAscending
        ? source.OrderBy(keySelector)
        : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T_PO> SortedPO(this IQueryable<T_PO> query,  ExtjsGridPagingParameter.SortingParameter sortingParameter)
{
    bool isAscending = sortingParameter.direction == "ASC";

    switch (sortingParameter.property)
    {
        case "po_code":
            return query.OrderBy(item => item.po_code, isAscending);
        case "proj_name":
            return query.OrderBy(item => item.T_PROJECT.proj_name, isAscending);
        case "po_supplier_contact":
            return query.OrderBy(item => item.po_supplier_contact, isAscending);
        case "po_grandtotal":
            return query.OrderBy(item => item.po_grandtotal, isAscending);
        case "po_docdate":
            return query.OrderBy(item => item.po_docdate, isAscending);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Salute you (-/\-)

Comment: I was thinking about using manually constructed `Expression`s for this, but: 1. It would be messier than this code 2. the special case for `proj_name` would be hard to do.

Comment: @svick it was my first thought as well, but I went this way due to reasons exactly as you described